# Динамическое заполнение списка GridView из дочернего Activity в родительское

Tags: android, activity, gridview

Делаю приложение список дел, никак не могу реализовать заполнение списка, находящегося в родительском Activity(далее MainActivity), данными из дочернего Activity(далее ActivityTwo).GridView находится в MainActivity, в ActivityTwo находится EditText  из которого написанные данные должны поступать в GridView.Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил) Сделал изменения из ответа, но результата не получил, вот код (MainActivity)

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 Intent intent = null; Intent intent1 = null; GridView griidV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    griidV = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.dol);
    final ArrayList<String> session = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, session);
    griidV.setAdapter(adapter);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String edittextData = extras.getString("name");
}}
```

(ActivityTwo)

```
    public class ActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn1;
Button btn2;
EditText edT1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    edT1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edT1);
   Intent(ActivityTwo.this,MainActivity.class);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this,MainActivity.class);
            String edittextData = edT1.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("name",edittextData);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}}
```

Comment: Если вы вызываете второе активити из первого и вам нужно получить результат работы второй активити в первой, то это делается через метод `startActivityForResult()` для вызова второй и обработку колбэка с результатом в `onActivityResult()` первой. [Пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-29-vyzyvaem-activity-i-poluchaem-rezultat-metod-startactivityforresult.html). Вызывая первую активити из второй, как вы сейчас делаете, вы накопите огромный стек переходов, который совершенно не нужен.

Comment: так же, данные вы получили в `edittextData` первой активити, но никак их не иcпользуете. мало просто перекинуть данные из одной активити в другую. Теперь надо их добавить в список для GridView и обновить адаптер. Кто по вашему и как должен догадаться, что вы там что то переслали и как это использовать